# "This feature is beta version" message display on map

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, dictionary, gmsmapview

I am using GMSMapView for map functionality. and it display "This feature is beta version" on map when run app in device.

How to remove this message?

Comment: Need to change your SDK

Comment: Update your POD

Comment: i installed  GoogleMaps-2.2.0. but still getting same issue